# Unrecognizability of HALT

Tags: turing-machines, automata

I am currently stuck on a question from Sipser's book of automata. The question goes like this:

> Consider the following language: V = {w|w = 0a for some a which is an
>   element of HALT} U {w|w=1b for some b which is an element of
>   complement of HALT }
>
> Prove that V is unrecognizable? Prove that complement of V is
>   unrecognizable?

I kinda know that to prove them we have to use contradiction but I got stuck after that and haven't been able to come up with any solution up till now. Any pointers/hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ was recognizable then the language of Halting problem could be reduced to $V$ as following.

Let $M_V$ be a TM recognizing $V$, i.e, $M_V$ accepts $x$ if $x \in V$. Let $u$ be some string (description of a TM). Then we run $M_V$ on $0u$ and $1u$ by [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)). $M_V$ will eventually halt on one of these inputs since $u$ is either in $HALT$ or not in $HALT$. So, when it halts we simply check: if $M$ has halted on $0u$ then $u \in HALT$, else if $M$ has halted on 1u then $u \notin HALT$. Thus this implies that $HALT$ is decidable which is impossible.

Similarly for $\overline{V}$. Let $u$ be some string (description of a TM). If $M_{\overline{V}}$ accepts $0u$ then $u \notin HALT$. If $M_{\overline{V}}$ accepts $1u$ then $u \in HALT$.

Comment: What does element of halt mean here?

Comment: @SagarP $HALT = \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM and } M \text{ halts on } w\}$.

Comment: Hey, I have one silly doubt. In 2nd part where we find the complement of the language, why are you still considering union and not intersection ? It should be L1' intersection L2' and not L1' union L2' right ?

Comment: @SagarP You are right, $\overline{V} = \overline{L_1} \cap \overline{L_2}$ and I don't claim that it is union. I simply use the fact that  $\forall u \notin HALT$, $0u \in \overline{V}$ and $\forall u \in HALT$, $1u \in \overline{V}$ by the definition of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Complement of first part is 0u such that for all u, u does not halt on w. Complement of second part is 1u such that for all u, u does halt on w. Now their intersection seems like $\phi$ to me which is regular. @fade2black

Comment: @SagarP complement of $L_1$ contains also strings starting with $1$.

Comment: I have seen you answering compiler questions. So if possible can you answer this question for me ? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84471/symbol-table-usage?noredirect=1#comment181283_84471